# Show two frames where one of them is in the corner of a webpage

Tags: html, iframe, frame, frameset-iframe

I'm trying to show a small frame on the bottom right corner, like in the below picture:
[image]

I've search a lot about frames (including framesets) and iframes because I need both frames to be loading separately. For example, I can go to different pages in frame 1 without affecting or reloading frame 2. But I was only able to show them side by side.

Any help would be great!! Thanks!

Comment: Make `frame 2` `position:absolute` and put it at wherever you want.

Comment: Include a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)